# mpi4py Split_type using openmpi's OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET

Tags: mpi, mpi4py

Is it possible to split a communicator using openmpi's OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET in mpi4py?

I've verified this works:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

sharedcomm = comm.Split_type(MPI.COMM_TYPE_SHARED)
```

but this does not:

```
socketcomm = comm.Split_type(MPI.OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET)
```

nor does this:

```
socketcomm = comm.Split_type(MPI.COMM_TYPE_SOCKET)
```

I've looked at the docs but I can't find anything about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mpi4py` only provides a wrapper around standard MPI features. `OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET` is an Open MPI specific split type. You may still use it in `mpi4py` if you know its numeric value as it is just a member of a C `enum`:

```c
/*
 * Communicator split type constants.
 * Do not change the order of these without also modifying mpif.h.in
 * (see also mpif-common.h.fin).
 */
enum {
  MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED,
  OMPI_COMM_TYPE_HWTHREAD,
  OMPI_COMM_TYPE_CORE,
  OMPI_COMM_TYPE_L1CACHE,
  OMPI_COMM_TYPE_L2CACHE,
  OMPI_COMM_TYPE_L3CACHE,
  OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET,  // here
  OMPI_COMM_TYPE_NUMA,
  OMPI_COMM_TYPE_BOARD,
  OMPI_COMM_TYPE_HOST,
  OMPI_COMM_TYPE_CU,
  OMPI_COMM_TYPE_CLUSTER
};
#define OMPI_COMM_TYPE_NODE MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED
```

Being a member of an `enum` means that the actual numerical value of `OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET` depends on its position in the `enum` and hence may differ from one release of Open MPI to another. You have several options here.

#### Hardcode the value

This is the simplest option. Open `mpi.h` (`ompi_info --path incdir` gives you its location), count the position of `OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET` in the enclosing `enum` starting with `0` for `MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED` and hardcode the value. The code may break with releases of Open MPI different from yours.

#### Parse `mpi.h`

Read `mpi.h`, search for `enum` definitions and find the one containing `OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET`. Provided that `MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED` is `0`, the value of `OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET` is its 0-based index in the sequence of enum values. This depends a lot on the code in `mpi.h` having a specific format and can easily break if that changes.

#### Parse `mpif.h`

The Fortran interface is easier to parse as there the value is defined as:

```
parameter (OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET=6)
```

This is easily parsable with a simple regular expression. The problem is that recent versions of Open MPI split `mpif.h` over a couple of files that are then included from `mpif.h` and currently the value is in `mpif-constants.h`. So you may need to parse the `include` statements and recurse into the files they reference. Note that those are Fortran `include` statements and not preprocessor `#include` directives.

#### Code generation

Write a small C program that outputs the value of `OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET` to a Python file and run it as part of your program's setup procedure. Something like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: mkompimod /path/to/module.py\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *fh = fopen(argv[1], "w");
    if (fh != NULL) {
        fprintf(fh, "COMM_TYPE_SOCKET = %d\n", OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET);
        fclose(fh);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Put that in a file named `mkompimod.c`. Compile with `mpicc -o mkompimod mkompimod.c` and run with `mkompimod /path/to/ompi.py` to create a Python file `ompi.py` with the value of `OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET`. Import it and use it in the call to `comm.Split_type()`:

```py
import ompi

socketcomm = comm.Split_type(ompi.COMM_TYPE_SOCKET)
```

#### Write a Python module in C

That's a bit involved, but you can write a C module that includes `mpi.h` and exports the value of `OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET` as a Python constant. Consult the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) on how to write extensions in C.

#### Use the CFFI module

[CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) lets you build Python modules that wrap C libraries and writes all the glue code for you. Put the following in a file named `ompi_build.py`:

```py
from cffi import FFI

ffi = FFI()
ffi.set_source("ompi", r"#include <mpi.h>")
ffi.cdef(
   r"""
   const int OMPI_COMM_TYPE_HWTHREAD;
   ... more constants here ...
   const int OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET;
   ... even more constants here ...
   """
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   ffi.compile(verbose=True)
```

Run like this:

```
$ CC=mpicc python ompi_build.py
```

This will create the C module `ompi.c` and compile it into a loadable DSO. You may then import it and access the constant like this:

```py
from ompi.lib import OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET

socketcomm = comm.Split_type(OMPI_COMM_TYPE_SOCKET)
```

CFFI provides integration with Python's `distutils` and you can have it automatically build the C module as part of the setup process.

#### Use Cython

That's what `mpi4py` itself is written in. It blends C and Python into a single cryptic syntax. Read the source code. Try to figure out what's going on and how to write something yourself. Can't help you there.

---

Whichever path you choose, keep in mind that all this pertains to the system on which the program will be running, not only the system on which the program will be developed.

Comment: Very interesting! MPI-4 (now ratified!) will allow for more split types, but they will be implementation dependent.